# Wrong characters in Code Generation and T4 Text Templates

Tags: c#, templates, generics, t4

While generating controllers, contracts and implementation for a WCF service, I use the

```
 Microsoft FxCop 1.35\FxCopSdk.dll
 Microsoft FxCop 1.35\Microsoft.Cci.dll
```

to get information about the underlying business object classes.

a relevant piece of code generate such a controller like:

*excerpt from webservice.tt:*

```
    public <#=meth.ReturnType.Name#> <#=meth.Name #> (<#=parametersIn#>) {
        return <#=meth.DeclaringType.Name#>.<#=meth.Name#>(<#=parametersOut#>);
    }
```

and normally generates something like

```
    public Employee GetEmployee (Int64 id) {
        return EmployeeController.GetEmployee(id);
    }
```

**however**

when introducing generics, where the `meth.ReturnType.Name` is a generic collection weird characters are generated and the generated code becomes broken.

eg I generate a controller into the BLL Assembly first like:

```
    public static PagedList<<#=t.Name#>> 
    GetAll<#=t.Name#>s(string sortby, int pageindex, int pagesize) {
        return <#=t.Name#>.GetPaged(sortby, pageindex, pagesize);
    }
```

that results in:

```
    public static PagedList<Employee> 
    GetAllEmployees(string sortby, int pageindex, int pagesize) {
        return Employee.GetPaged(sortby, pageindex, pagesize);
    }
```

that seems to go well and the assembly builds.
But then when I use the introspection on this assembly to generate code in the 
WCF assembly, e.g. to generate servicecontracts like:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "<#=meth.Name#><#=parametersTemplate#>")]
    <#=meth.ReturnType.Name#> <#=meth.Name#> (<#=parametersIn#>);
```

it generates wrong code:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
    UriTemplate = "GetAllEmployees?sortby={sortby}&pageindex={pageindex}&pagesize={pagesize}")]
    PagedList`1<Portal.BLL.BO.Employee> GetAllEmployees (String sortby, Int32 pageindex, Int32 pagesize);
```

mind the **`1** (apostrophe and 1) after the returntypename, before the lower than symbol on the bottom line. This happens to all generated code that contain generic returntypes.

**Does the introspector picks something up wrong here or is it an encoding problem?**

Comment: It's not encoding problem, `PagedList'1<Portal.BLL.BO.Employee>` - it is what generic type looks like
`'1` - means that this is generic type with one type parametr. You need to manualy construct this return type in order to get it work

Comment: Aha, thanks for this very useful information? Mind to put it as an answer here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not encoding problem, `PagedList'1<Portal.BLL.BO.Employee>` - it is what generic type looks like `'1` - means that this is generic type with one type parametr. You need to manualy construct this return type in order to get it work